# Showing property filter value in Django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters

I have the follwoing models in my Django project:

```
class File(models.Model):
  client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='client_files')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
  ...
```

```
class FileTracking(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(File, related_name='file_tracking', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    active =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

my view:

```
class FileCurrentView(ListView):
    model = File
    template_name = 'files_current.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            user=self.request.user
            current_files = files.filter(...)
            ...
            context["user"] = user
            context["current_files"]= current_files
            ...
        return context
```

In my template, I want to show the description or title of the last active record.

I tried to create a property in the `FileTracking` model:

```
@property
def LastActiveTrack(self):
    result  = self.objects.filter(active=1).order_by("-date")[0].title
    result_txt = str(result)
    if result:            
        return result_txt
    return ''
```

in my template:

```
{% for file in current_files %}
    Title: {{file.title}}
    last Tracking: {{file.file_tracking.LastActiveTrack}}
{% endif %}
```

but I couldn't get the value of the `LastActiveTrack` in my template. Any ideas?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but you should prepare all the data in your view instead of doing ad-hoc DB queries in your template in a `for` loop, that's very inefficient. If you will do that, you will debug it way easier as it doesnt swallow errors the same way as the template does. Also if you are filtering via `active` field you should add `db_index=True` to that column. And a bonus unsolicited tip: you should prefix boolean column with `is_` so it's obvious it's a boolean value, it will improve the code readability in a long run.

Comment: You can just get the last active in the template itself no need for property method like this:

    ```last Tracking: {{file.file_tracking_set.filter(active=1).order_by("-date").first().title }}```

Comment: thanks @yedpodtrzitko for your valuable comments.
anyway, I am not sure if I understod your first comment very well, actually i use user to get some other data (like dashboard), or can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Ahtisham thanks, but it doesn't work. per the error message, and as i know, Django templates does't allow data filtration.
error message: Could not parse the remainder: '(active=1).order_by("-date").first().title' from 'file.file_tracking.filter(active=1).order_by("-date").first().title'

Comment: Note, current `LastActiveTrack` implementation cannot return last track per file, it can only return the very last track of all files. Also this implementation will show bad performance. It is usually better to reduce number of queries executed per view and I'd suggest to collect all needed data in `FileCurrentView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in your template is less than ideal as you will make a database call for each file, which may get expensive in overhead if you have a lot of files.

Better to update your initial call to include each file's filtracking via [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), which should limit it to two DB calls

```
current_files = files.filter(...).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'file_tracking', 
        queryset=FileTracking.objects.order_by("-date"),
        #to make it clear what we are referring to in our template
        #add a to_attr argument to Prefetch
        to_attr="filetrack_ordered"
    )
)
```

then in your template you can call:

```
{% for file in current_files %}
    Title: {{file.title}}
    last Tracking: {{file.filetrack_ordered.0.title}}
{% endif %}
```

NB: in your question you seem to be looking for file_tracking.title which isn't actually mentioned in the model fields you provide. I've assumed it's in there somewhere.

Comment: thanks @SamSparx ; 
your way of solving this issue looks great. actually, i tried to use prefetch before but i wasn't confedent about my code.
anyway, the code compiled with no errors;  but, also, does not pop any data into my template !! 
as you mentioned.. I have a title field (with data). and i was updating the question to include that field a munit before you posted your response.
any ideas why not having the result ?

Comment: Try removing `.0.title` in your template to see if there's anything being pulled from FileTracking and make sure title isn't blank in the ones you are looking at.

Comment: To summarize, your solution is correct.
I removed the .0.title => no data.
I started to use shell and manipulate the query line by line. 
After some trials and errors, I got a result when used only one filter.... when adding another filter, data disappears.
Finally I grouped the filter in brackets, like this (files.filter(...) | files.filter(...)).prefetch_related ... 

and it worked.